# Aggregate column of list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Week     Name    Value
------------------------
1       [A,V,C]  [4,6,2]
2       [A,B,D]  [3,7,1]
3       [X,Y,Z]  [2,5,10]
4       [D,G,M]  [1,2,3]
```

How can I aggregate the list in the 'value' column?
e.g.

```
Week     Name    Value     sum
------------------------------
1       [A,V,C]  [4,6,2]   12
2       [A,B,D]  [3,7,1]   11
3       [X,Y,Z]  [2,5,10]  17
4       [D,G,M]  [1,2,3]   6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apply` like this:

```
df["sum"] = df["Value"].apply(sum)
```

Relevant pandas docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just another way even though I found Alex's solution to be more elegant.

```
df['sum'] = [sum(i) for i in df['Value']]
```